# discord.js channel only command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, command, channel

Kepps crashing

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
 
module.exports = {
    name: 'not-dropping',
    description: 'sets the dropping status!',
    
    if (message.channel.id === '1059798572855476245') {
      execute(message, args) {
        message.delete(1000);
        
 
        const name = ("dropping-")
 
 
        message.channel.setName(name)
        message.channel.send(`Successfully set the dropping status to **${name}**`)
    }
}
}
```

I also tried to change it to Role only but it contiunes crashing.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Having an if-statement in the definition of your export won't work. Instead, call the if-statement only when `execute()` is run, like this:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
 
module.exports = {
  name: 'not-dropping',
  description: 'sets the dropping status!',
  
  execute(message, args) {
    if (message.channel.id === '1059798572855476245') {
      message.delete(1000);
      
      const name = ("dropping-")
      message.channel.setName(name)
      message.channel.send(`Successfully set the dropping status to **${name}**`)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Do you mind marking my answer with a check mark? Then it will be apparent, that this has been successfully resolved